# Error on fetching firstofDefault() on multithreaded environment intermittently

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, entity-framework, linq

We have a report scheduler engine, which is a windows service which will pick the report details ( queries, parameters, etc ) from DB which is scheduled to be generated on a specific time of the day, and run the queries to generate report.

(EF5 code first with MySQL Database )

This is how it works :

1. There is an MSMQ Queue which will have the ID of a report pulled by a polling service.
2. The Schedule Report generator will peek the MSMQ Queue for Report ID, and pick the Report Details from DB and generate the report.

The entire process works fine until friday morning. We have 2 reports scheduled now which is set for 8:00AM and 8:15AM everyday. The reports gets generated every day except friday, when we run into an exception which the Step 2 ( Scheduler tries to pick the report details from the DB ).

My Code to pick the report details are as :

```
public void RunScheduler(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        List<ReportScheduler> schedules;
        try
        {

            schedules = _scheduler.PickFromMSMQToExecute();
            if (schedules == null || schedules.Count == 0) return;

            Parallel.ForEach(schedules, currentSchld =>
            { 
                CreateScheduledReport(currentSchld, dateTime);
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

This calls a function  :

```
      private void CreateScheduledReport(ReportScheduler schedule, DateTime dateTime)
        {
            _logger = new Log4netFactory().Create("ReportSchedulerService");
            Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
            var schedulerLog = new ReportSchedulerLog
            {
                SchedulerRequestID = schedule.RequestID,
                StartDateTime = dateTime,
                Status = "0",
                UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now
            };

            timer.Start();
            var startedTime = DateTime.Now;

            var saveSuccess = true;
            try
            {
                var report = _reportRepository.GetReportforScheduling(schedule.ReportID);
                GenerateReport(report);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {}
}
```

The table "Reports" has a userId, which has a foreign key reference to "users" table. In the try block the call GetReportforScheduling, is the function calling the context repository like :

```
  public Report GetReportforScheduling(int id)
        {
            Report rpt = new Report();
            String level = String.Empty;
            try
            {
                level = "connecting DB if closed";
                ReConnectDatabase(context);
                level += ",picking the report for Report ID :" + id.ToString();
                rpt = context.Reports.Where(t => t.ReportID == id).Include(m => m.User).FirstOrDefault();
                level += ",Picked the report successfully";
                if (null == rpt) return new Report();
                level += ",Fetching the parameters";
                rpt.ReportDetails = context.ReportDetails.Where(x => x.ReportId == id).ToList();
                rpt.HasDetail = context.ReportParameters.Any(x => x.ReportTemplateParameters.Any(t => t.TemplateId == rpt.TemplateID) && !(x.IsDynamic == "1"));

                level += ",Parameters fetched";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Info("Error Level :" + level);
                _logger.Error("Error on picking the report / details from the DB :" + ex.Message, ex);
            }
            return rpt;
        }
```

The line :

```
rpt = context.Reports.Where(t => t.ReportID == id).Include(m => m.User).FirstOrDefault();
```

Gives the issue on every friday, if we restart the windows service, it runs as excepted too. The exception raised is as :

> 2015-12-25 23:59:39,703 [19] ReportScheduler.Service.exe INFO 
>   EIS.DataAccess.Repository.ReportRepository
>   GetReportforScheduling - Error Level :connecting DB if closed,picking
>   the report for Report ID :15
>
> 2015-12-25 23:59:39,718 [19]
>   ReportScheduler.Service.exe ERROR
>   EIS.DataAccess.Repository.ReportRepository
>   GetReportforScheduling - Error on picking the report / details from
>   the DB :An error occurred while executing the command definition. See
>   the inner exception for details.
>
> EIS.Infrastructure.Logger.EISException: An error occurred
>   while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for
>   details.    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>     at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext
>   context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
>     at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__a()<br>
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>     at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__9()<br>
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)
>     at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)
>     at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()<br>
>   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>     at
>   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()<br>    at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
>  
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()<br>    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source)
>     at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.b__1[TResult](IEnumerable`1
>   sequence)<br>    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1
>   query, Expression queryRoot)
>     at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expression)
>     at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expression)
>     at
>   System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>   at
>   EIS.DataAccess.Repository.ReportRepository.GetReportforScheduling(Int32
>   id)

Is this because of the multi threaded environment or lazy loading of the user's context ?

Comment: I'm not sure about "every friday" thing, but you should definitely create own context for each thread, as virtually all .net instance methods are not thread-safe.

Comment: Makes sense, but then it should fail always then. As the scheduler pulls up the execution, only one thread happens to execute currently.

Comment: When the `context` is created ? , what is `reconnectdatabase` ? I prefer the way @AlexSkalozub suggested. EF is not thread safe so create instance in each thread and dispose it.

Comment: @Jinith first of all, the number of threads executing at a time can be more than one (multi-core processors and everything). And even if it happens that only one thread is processing your database activities, operations as complex as database queries are not atomic, so scheduler may switch threads in the middle of request (say, when thread is waiting data from db socket) and another thread will start writing another request to the same socket while database is not expecting it. So if method is not specially designed with thread safety in mind, it can lead to race conditions.

Comment: Context is created on the constructor of the call with the function GetReportforScheduling(). ReconnectDatabase, is checking if the connection is still open, and if not opens it.

Comment: One context per request is the rule of thumb. Just create a new context before you access the repository

Comment: Thanks all, I would definitely go ahead with creating a new context before accessing repository for every thread. Wanted to take opinions on why it could not work on a specific period repeatedly.

Comment: Who knows? Maybe your server is being maintained on Fridays, so responses take more time and there's higher possibility for race conditions.